# SQL query - how to get data as result some value that does not exist as data in table (Goods and Services)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, percentage

I have table T1:

```
NAME        GOODS1    .GOODS2  SERVICES
TELENOR       100        0      0
VIP           100       200     350
T-MOBILE      100       100     50
```

I MUST get result in only two columns:

```
GOODS      60
SERVICES   40
```

So result is:
In first column always as values GOODS and SERVICES (how to put them as data?)
In second is calculation in PERCENTAGE of SUMs:

```
where SUM(GOODS)=SUM(GOODS1+GOODS2)
```

and

```
sum(SERVICES)=sum(SERVICES)
```

So Total amount is `1000`.
Goods are `600(100+100+200+100+100)`. (so it is 60% of 1000)
Services are `350+50=400` - so it is 40% of 1000.

Also how to do this calculation?
Thank  you very much!!!!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT 
  'GOODS' AS Name, 
  (SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2)) / (SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) + SUM(Services)) * 100 AS Total
FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'SERVICES' AS Name, 
  SUM(Services) / (SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) + SUM(Services)) * 100 AS Total
FROM T1
```

That will give you:

```
NAME        TOTAL
GOODS       60
SERVICES    40
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you expected output 1000 as overall total, 600 as Goods total and 400 as Services total.

If so, try this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) + SUM(Services) as OverallTotal,
  SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) as GoodsTotal,
  SUM(Services) as ServicesTotal
FROM T1
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/311904/2).

-EDIT

If you're looking at getting those as 2 distinct rows, you could try `UNION`:

```
SELECT 100*GoodsTotal/OverallTotal
FROM (
SELECT 
  SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) + SUM(Services) as OverallTotal,
  SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) as GoodsTotal,
  SUM(Services) as ServicesTotal
FROM T1) AS T
UNION
SELECT 100*ServicesTotal/OverallTotal 
FROM (
SELECT 
  SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) + SUM(Services) as OverallTotal,
  SUM(Goods1) + SUM(Goods2) as GoodsTotal,
  SUM(Services) as ServicesTotal
FROM T1) AS T
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/311904/22).
Good luck.

Comment: this is not what i wanted. i wanted in first column to literally be "GOODS" and in second row"SERVICES"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ((TotalGoods * 100)/ Total) as TotalPercentGoods,
    ((TotalServices * 100) / Total) as TotalPercentServices
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(Goods1)+SUM(Goods2)+SUM(SERVICES) as Total,
        SUM(Goods1)+SUM(Goods2) as TotalGoods,
        SUM(Services) as TotalServices
    FROM T1 
) as l
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/311904/26)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach:

```
select c.which,
       sum(case when which = 'GOODS' then Goods1 + GOod2
                else Services
           end) / sum(Goods1+Goods2+Services)*100
from table 1 cross join
     (select 'GOODS' as which union all select 'SERVICES' end) c
```

This should only require scanning the table once.